# Inheritance of JFrame

Tags: swing, inheritance

I need a selected item to be printed when button Search is clicked, but it prints initial value, not selected one. It must be due to inheritance between Selection and Data but what exactly I do not understand. Due to what does it happen? 
I will be very pleased to all useful advices.

```
public class Selection extends JFrame {

    JLabel currency;
    protected JComboBox currencies;
    JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    public Selection() {
        final GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(gbl);
        final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        currency = new JLabel("Currency:");
        String[] cur = {"USD", "EUR"};
        currencies = new JComboBox(cur);
        currencies.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        search.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        search.setFocusPainted(false);
        search.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        search.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 23));
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        c.gridx = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(currency, c);
        add(currency);
        gbl.setConstraints(currencies, c);
        add(currencies);
        gbl.setConstraints(search, c);
        add(search);
        search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Data data = new Data();
                data.print();
            }
        });
    }

    protected String getCurrency() {
        return String.valueOf(currencies.getSelectedItem());
    }
}

public class Data extends Selection {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(getCurrency());
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame selection = new Selection();
                selection.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                selection.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                selection.setVisible(true);
                selection.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each button press, you create a *new* `Data` object. That means that its method `print()` shall always print `"USD"`, because the selection in the new `Data` object cannot be changed.

To fix the problem you can remove completely the `Data` class and implement the method `print()` inside the `Selection` class. Then, on the action listener simply call `print()`, without any reference.